# turtlebot2 doesn't work with amcl_demo.launch

Tags: ros, navigation, turtlebot2, turtlebot, amcl-demo.launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I launched amcl with turtlebot2, but turtlebot2 doesn't move. I have installed ROS hydro on my PC. When I launched amcl on groovy, my turtlebot2 moved correctly. I checked some topic with rostopic echo command.

/navigation_velocity_smoother/raw_cmd_vel and /cmd_vel_mux/input/navi don't respond.

/move_base_simple/goal outputs values.

/mobile_base/commands/velocity outputs values when I touched bumper sensor.

I launched a following command.

- roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch (on turtlebot PC)
- ssh turtlebot@turtlebot(on workstation)
- roslaunch turtlebot_navigation amcl_demo.launch map_file:=/tmp/my_map.yaml(on workstation set to point to turtlebot PC)
- roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_navigation.launch(on workstation PC)

It has a warn.
[Warn] Waiting on transform from base_footprint to map to become available before running costmap, tf error:

if anybody correctly moves a turtlebot on hydro, I want you to teach me how to move.
and I want any clue to solve this problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/139701/turtlebot2-doesn%27t-work-with-amcl_demo.launch./) by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 894 on 2014-03-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-03-13**:
I can move a turtlebot2 with keyboard_teleop and ps3 joystick.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-03-13**:
If I hit a next message on a terminal in ssh turtlebot@turtlebot, my turtlebot went straight.

$rostopic pub -1 /cmd_vel_mux/input/navi geometry_msgs/Twist -- '[0.3, 0.0, 0.0]' '[0.1, 0.0, 0.0]'

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-03-18**:
As I guessed this problem parameter, I refered the following URL to repair my yaml.
http://answers.ros.org/question/78196/sensor-raytrace-error-when-maps-set-to-voxel/
After that,  a warning said "you must specify at least three points for the robot footprint reverting to previous footprint.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-03-18**:
This alarm was described on costmap_2d_ros.cpp. So, I added footprint to costmap_common_param.yaml.
All warnings and error was gone on the terminal, but my turtlebot2 doesn't work!! I drag a mouse after pushing 2D Nav Goal on Rviz.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-03-18**:
I hit next command on my workstation with ssh turtlebot@turtlebot.
$rostopic pub -1 /move_base_simple/goal geometry_msgs/PoseStamped '{header: {frame_id:"map"}, pose:{position: {x: 0.5, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, orientation: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 1.0}}}'
My Turtlebot moved, but my problem not yet.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-03-18**:
I guessed that this problem was network configuration. if I hit rostopic pub -r10 /hello std_msgs/String "hello" on workstation and rostopic echo /hello on Turtlebot, The message " hello" doesn't begin printed. Does anybody know how to fix it?

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2014-03-23**:
@Ken_in_JAPAN For the next time, better post additional information by editing your initial question instead of multiple comments (hard to read).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Many turtlebot user might miss to add IP address of workstation to /etc/hosts on turtlebot PC, because the explanation put 2.3 Configuring /etc/hosts on http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup only. It is important to set it to move a turtlebot. Please check it when you have same problem.

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0